# Ansible: how to fetch a value from a dictionary if the dictionary MIGHT be undefined

Tags: ansible

I need to fetch a value from a dictionary, that might be either defined or undefined, but I can't find a proper way.

Let's assume we have a dictionary:

```
- name: Define the dictionaty
  set_fact:
    my_dictionary:
      my_key: my_value
```

Then let's assume that we had to drop the dictionary at some point in some case:

```
- name: Drop the dictionary
  set_fact:                                                                                                                                                                                     
    my_dictionary:
```

And then I need to check if the dictionary defined and assign a variable from one of this dictionary's keys:

```
- name: Fetch the parameter from the dictionary or set the default value
  set_fact:
    my_var: >-
      (my_dictionary != None) | ternary(
        {{ my_dictionary.my_key }},
        'my_default_value'
      )
```

Wrong move!

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'None' has no attribute 'my_key'\n\nThe error appears to be in '***/test.yml': line 16, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Fetch the parameter from the dictionary or set the default value\n    ^ here\n"}
```

As I understood, Ansible tries to compute the values of the parameters of `ternary()` in any case. Well, I understand that Ansible is not a programming language, so I shouldn't expect that it will act like a programming language. :-) But, anyhow, how to fetch a value from a dictionaty if the dictionary *might* be set to `None`?

The only (ugly) way I've found is something like that:

```
- name: Fetch the parameter from the dictionary
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_dictionary.my_key }}"
  when:
    my_dictionary != None

- name: Set the default value
  set_fact:
    my_var: 'my_default_value'
  when:
    my_dictionary == None
```

Though I'd rather use some shorter form.

Would anyone be so kind as to share a hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`default()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) filter is for.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo:
    baz:
      bar: not the default
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo.bar | default('my_default_value') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ bar.bar | default('my_default_value') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ baz.bar | default('my_default_value') }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "my_default_value"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "my_default_value"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "not the default"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The point is that I need the key to be fetched if another condition yields `true`. I will add this to the question and post the updated version soon.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood all your requirements correctly but the code seems to be way more complicated that it needs to be.

How about define dict:

```
-set_fact:
   my_dictionary:
     1: one
```

If dict is defined grab the value

```
-set_fact:
   my_var: "{{ my_dictionary.1 }}"
 when: my_dictionary is defined
```

Else set it to value of your choice:

```
-set_fact:
   my_var: two
 when: my_dictionary is not defined
```

Slava Ukraini!

Comment: Geroyam slava! Thank you!